# How do I use javascript control ipad to scroll uniformly (without friction)

Tags: javascript, ipad, scroll

I would need to listen to onscroll, and know how fast it is scrolling. Any one have any ideas how this should be implemented? By using onmousedown and onmouseup? And how should I calculate the speed?

Comment: yeah, but, is that accurate? Like how do I synchronize it as exactly so that a word under a finger will always be under that finger until I release it, and then it goes uniform speed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe iScroll might be of help. It provides a way to scroll content inside a fixed width/height element. You should be able to disable the change in speed as it nears the end of a scroll.

You can find more information on it here:

http://cubiq.org/iscroll